# Self join to a table

Tags: sql, self-join

I have a table like

```
Employee
==================
name      salary
==================
a        10000
b        20000
c        5000
d        40000
```

i want to get all the employee whose salary is greater than A's salary.
I don't want to use any nested or sub query. 
It has been asked in an interview and hint was to use self join. I really can't figure out how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
select e1.* from Employee e1, Employee e2  where 
           e2.name = 'a' and
           e1.salary > e2.salary
```

Using self join

```
 select e1.* from Employee e1 join Employee e2  on 
           e2.name = 'a' and
           e1.salary > e2.salary
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT emp1.* FROM Employee emp1 JOIN Employee emp2
ON emp2.Name = 'A' and emp1.Salary > emp2.Salary
```

Comment: this will work. only modification will be mysql are case sensitive so emp2.Name = 'A' should be emp2.Name = 'a'