# How do I get a query result to be put into the result of another query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that looks like this:

Persons:

```
+---------+----------+----------+
| ID      | name     | clientID |
+---------+----------+----------+
|001      | carl     |002       |
|002      | fred     |null      |
+---------+----------+----------+
```

I want the result to be:

```
+---------+----------+
| name    | client   |
+---------+----------+
|carl     | fred     |
+---------+----------+
```

I can get the output of people with clients with that clients ID (with the following) but not sure how to get the clients name to replace it.

```
select name, client
from schema.persons
where client is not null
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to learn about joins.

Comment: you'd need a self-join, to boot: `select * from persons left join persons as client on persons.clientID = clients.ID`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self join to a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035105/self-join-to-a-table)

Answer (score 4):

You can implement a self join

```
SELECT p.name,
       c.name as client
  FROM schema.persons p
       JOIN schema.persons c
         ON( p.clientID = c.id )
```